# Mouse coordinates on Screen

Tags: c#

How to track the mouse position on the screen regardless of application.i.e. Whenever the user clicks or select something with mouse in any application, i want to display my own menu at that point itself.

Is there any way to get mouse position on the screen using c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'd need to P/Invoke to user32.dll and use `SetWindowsHookEx()`.

Have a look here:

- [SetWindowsHookEx (user32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowsHookEx.html)
- [How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;318804#3)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bad idea. I'm sure you could force it with a bit of effort, but what about the other applications that may want to show their own menus when the mouse is clicked?

Comment: No, i don't want to do anything with the existing things. Just i want to display some icon on the selection of some text or Image...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue, I used Low Level Mouse hooks and Low Level Keyboard hooks to implement the solution.

I am yet to add the Menu part of it.